# 150 Word Count Regex

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that allows no more than 150 words. I have tried couple of expressions, but all of them count characters, not words.

My attempts:

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,150}$
^(?:\w+\W+){0,150}(?:\w+)$
^(\w*\W*){0,250}$
```

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing, but if I understand things correctly, you probably want something like `"\W*(/w+/W*){0,150}"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I meant, with the regular expression user should not be abe to write more than 150 words. I want to set this validtion to a text area on my form. I will try this. Really appreciate it

Comment: What if all words stick together? with no space between?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by restricting the input using regular expressions. regex is used to extract or match patterns. You can use this information to restrict the input.

Below regular expression will match a statement with 150 "words".

```
^(?:\s*\S+){1,150}$

^ Anchor to the beginning of the input
$ Anchor to the endof the input
\s: Space character
\S: Non space character
(?:xxx): Grouping without capturing
{1,150} : Match 1 - 150 instances of the preceding expression
```

I use double quotes for a word, since it will count the below sentence as made of 6 words and 7 words respectively, due to the space before the period

```
I am happy. This is good
I am happy . This is good
```

You can remove the ^ and $ sign from the expression to simply extract the first 150 words, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much. I meant, with the regular expression user should not be abe to write more than 150 words. I want to set this validtion to a text area on my form. I will try this. Really appreciate it

Comment: This regex will have problems... Because this is based on the separator (space) characters rather than on the words, this will count loose non-white-space characters such as punctuation as words, and hyphened composites a single word.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,149}$
```

This should do it for you.

See demo for `5`.

https://regex101.com/r/bT4kP8/2

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this. Really appreciate it

Comment: This regex has problems. If the input starts with a non-word character, the entire regex fails. It also can only handle white-space characters between words, and requires at least one white-space character between any words past the first, which will make the regex fail at any punctuation or hyphened words.

Comment: Considering that the OP has already attempted to account for line-breaks in his first attempt with `[\s\r\n]*`, and that 150 words is a lot for text without punctuation, I think it's reasonable to expect that he will want to handle punctuation... In situations where the OP doesn't further specify limitations to the expected input, the context becomes the rule IMO. Here, the context is that of *at least* a paragraph; and IRL, punctuation can be and is expected in paragraphs, and so that is the expected here until disclaimed by the OP. Hence why I think your solution is not reasonable (yet).